# Python passing a function into a function: why do we use decorators?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Why do we use decorators that has 2 layers of functions, when we can just use 1 layer?

Ex:

```
def time_func(func):
    print('Starting')
    t0=time()
    out = func()
    print('Ending',time()-t0
    return out
```

Now time_func() can take in any function and do its job just like a decorator. What am I missing?

Comment: [Did you try it?](https://ideone.com/u2cznF)

Comment: The decorator is *not* called every time the decorated function is called.

Comment: user2357112 I tried it and I didn't use it AS a decorator. I used it just as a function.

Comment: and MaxiMouse, so what if the decorator is not called every time the decorated function is called? I know that's how it works technically but in practicality what benefit is there?

Comment: The decorator is called once and shall return a function that replaces the decorated function. By that definition alone the answer to your question should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

A decorator by definition takes a function and returns a new function which replaces the decorated function. Your function doesn’t do that, your function just takes a function and calls it; that’s not a decorator, that’s just the behavior of a function taking a callback.

As for why you’d use decorators at all, it’s to add functionality to functions without writing that code into the function itself, both keeping the decorated function simpler and keeping the decorating behavior reusable. The only other alternative would be to put the onus on the caller to wrap each function call, but that’s obviously also not very sensible.

Comment: could you elaborate on why a decorater is preferred over a callback when a callback seems to be able to accomplish the same thing in a more straightforward way? and why is it not sensible to just wrap the function calls?